# Recycler View Adapter Manages List incorrectly

Tags: android, database, listview, android-recyclerview

Upon deletion of item from database, recycler view changes order of data after a one or two times of deleting and adding data to the list ,Deletion operation stop working or the Data in the list changes itself..

Activity which has the view and deletes from it

```
String[] items;
DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
    items = db.get_item();
    db.close();
     listRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);

    scheduleAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    if (listRecyclerView != null)
        listRecyclerView.setAdapter(scheduleAdapter);


    listRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new      WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    listRecyclerView.stopScroll();
listRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new   RItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), listRecyclerView, new  RItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongItemClick(View view,final int position) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MySchedule.this)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                .setTitle("Are you sure?")
                .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        DbHandler db = new DbHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        db.delete_item(items[1]);
                        db.close();

scheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",null)
                .show();


    }
}));


}
  @Override
    protected void onResume(){
    listRecyclerView.stopScroll();
    super.onResume();
    scheduleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

My adapter class

```
public class ScheduleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScheduleAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public int Type_Text = 1;
Context r_context;
int pos = 1;

public ScheduleAdapter (Context context){
    r_context=context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v; ViewHolder vItem = null;

    if (viewType==Type_Text){
        v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.typeview1,parent,false);
        vItem = new ViewHolder(v,viewType,parent.getContext());
    }

    return vItem;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder,final int position) {
    String[] Text_name;

    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    setAnimation(holder.container);

    pos = position;

    if(holder.HolderId==1){
        DbHandler db = new DbHandler(r_context);
        Text_name = db.get_item();
        holder.Text.setText(Text_name[position]);
        db.close();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    DbHandler db = new DbHandler(r_context);
    int note_count = db.get_count();
    db.close();
    return note_count;
}

public int getPosition (){
    return pos;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position){
    return Type_Text;
}

private void setAnimation (View view){

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(r_context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    view.startAnimation(animation);
}


// ViewHolder Class
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    int HolderId; TextView Text;
    CardView container;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, int View_Type, Context context) {
        super(itemView);

        container = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type1_cardview);

        if (View_Type==Type_Text){
            Text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type1_text);
            HolderId = 1;
        }
```

My Recycler view click listener class

```
public class RItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private OnItemClickListener mlistener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mgesturedetector;

public RItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
  mlistener = listener;
   mgesturedetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
          return true;
        }

      @Override
      public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
           View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
           if (child != null && mlistener != null) {
               mlistener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
           }
        }
    });

 }

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
     View childView = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
     if (childView != null && mlistener != null && mgesturedetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mlistener.onItemClick(childView, rv.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
 public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {}

@Override
 public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) { }
}
```

Somebody on stack overflow mentioned to implement this class to change the error this also didnt work

```
 public class WrapContentLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
 public WrapContentLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

//... constructor
@Override
      public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler,  RecyclerView.State state) {
    try {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "IndexOutOfBoundsException in RecyclerView happens");
    }
}
```

Kindly help! ...Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Sorry Been working on this whole day and just cant figure it out

Answer (score 0):

```
scheduleAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position,items.length);
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
```

Adding these lines after                         scheduleAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)
worked :)